# How to lead to catch for promise.all in react

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have a code like this

```
   requests = []
   ....
   ....
   Promise.all(requests).then((list) => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true
      });
    }).catch(() => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: false
      });
    });
```

I want to forcefully execute the catch block. What should I insert in requests that it gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. but in order to execute catch block you will have to manually throw an error in `.then` block at the end.

```
throw new Error('This is a Error');
```